# Simple Maps View Doesn't Work

Tags: android

I have a problem while creating a simple google maps view. Below you can find my code:

The manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB0zPyFFyQ_sCVmMjj6pgNqvqKg3zHGMSs"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

In Java File:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map); 
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}

}
```

In the XML File:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyB0zPyFFyQ_sCVmMjj6pgNqvqKg3zHGMSs"
    android:clickable="true" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

The result is a starting app, witch shows just gray area instead of the map, but with the typical google-icon in the corner.

I know the most common problem is an incorrect API key, but I checked it often and the key is correct.
Maybe someone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a key for the V2 API (judging from the comment in your manifest), but your implementation uses the V1 API. You basically have both API versions mixed up here. The V1 API requires an appropriate V1 API key to be placed as an attribute for the `MapView` in the XML layout. The V2 API requires the key to be placed in the manifest as you have done. Furthermore, the V2 API requires varous other stuff to be added into the manifest as well.

While you're using the V1 API, you need to obtain a V1 API key (which you can do until April, because it's deprecated). Alternatively, switch to using the V2 API which obviously you'd be encouraged to do (but watch out for the fact that it requires a later OpenGL version that isn't supported on some 2.2 devices).

I would suggest you follow the V2 API tutorial closely: [V2 Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)